# Как исправить ошибку 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'?

Tags: django

Пытаюсь сделать автоматический вход, после регистрации:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save()
        new_user = authenticate(email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                                )
        login(request, new_user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        print (form.errors)
else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Но после регистрации возникает ошибка -

> 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

указывает на login(request, new_user).
register.html:

```
<form  method="post">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <fieldset class="form-gorup">
        <legend class="border=bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Имя пользвоателя">
          </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputUsernameEmail" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" name="password1" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-gorup">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">SignUp</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

forms.py:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**UPDATE 1**
теперь так:
Функция регистрации:

```
class UserFormView(View):
form_class = UserRegestartinForm
template_name = 'users/register.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():     
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        new_user = User.objects.create(username=str(uuid.uuid4()), email=email,  first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'])
        new_user.set_password(password)
        new_user.save()


        needed_user = User.objects.get(email = email)            

        needed_user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)#ошибка появляется здесь

        if needed_user is not None:
            if needed_user.is_active:
                login(request, needed_user)
                return redirect('home')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form })
```

models.py:

```
class AdvancedUser(User):
phone_number = models.TextField(max_length=25, blank=True)
patronymic = models.TextField(max_length=60, blank=True)
сonfirmed_email = models.BooleanField(default = False)
сonfirmed_phone = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

forms.py:

```
class UserRegestartinForm(forms.ModelForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
#email = forms.EmailField()
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class Meta:
    model = models.AdvancedUser
    fields = ('first_name', 'email', 'password', 'confirm_password')
```

urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^register/', userViews.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
...
```

Пользователь в базу данных вносится, а вот дальше -

> ModuleNotFoundError at /register/
>   No module named 'path'

указывает на needed_user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

Comment: `new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],` может, потому что вход по юзернейму, а не по емейлу?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 обновил функцию. По email нельзя сделать? Уже и ошибка другая.

Comment: @xomem можно по email, только нужно [бэкенд аутентификации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/) своей написать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev написал [такой](https://pastebin.com/xceqmH5W) бэекенд, и получаю No module named 'user', на needed_user = authenticate(username=email, password=password). В settings бэкэнд указал

Comment: @xomem значит неправильно написали.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev думал, что правильно((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было добавить request в def authenticate:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EmailBackend(object):

def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except User.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        return None
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
    return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```